# Create class instance and inject it dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My project is using Nuxt, and I would like to implement dynamic injection of my services. It means I just add a class to my specific folder, and the class will be automatically injected into the context.

For instance, these are my classes placed in `nuxtApp/service`:

```
// /service/foo.service.js
export class FooService {
  constructor (context) {
    this.context = context
  }
  
  functionFoo (param) {
    console.log(`FooService.functionFoo: ${param}`)
  }
}

// /service/bar.service.js
export class BarService {
  constructor (context) {
    this.context = context
  }
  
  functionBar (param) {
    console.log(`BarService.functionBar: ${param}`)
  }
}
```

And this is how my plugin currently looks like, but I would like to automate it:

```
// /plugins/service-loader.js
import { FooService } from '../service/foo.service'
import { BarService } from '../service/bar.service'

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  const fooService = new FooService(app)
  inject('fooService', fooService)

  const barService = new BarService(app)
  inject('barService', barService)
}
```

Is it possible to create automatically loading of services placed in the `/service` folder, and then inject their instance into the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [Nuxt module](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/modules) to [provide plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/modules#provide-plugins) for `~/service/*.service.js`. The module would scan the `service/` directory, and call [`addPlugin()`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/internals-module-container#addplugin-template) for each `.service.js` file:

```js
// ~/modules/service-loader.js
import path from 'path'
import glob from 'glob'

export default function serviceLoader() {
  glob(path.resolve(__dirname, '../service/**/*.service.js'), { follow: true }, (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw err

    for (const file of files) {
      const exportedMembers = Object.keys(require(file))
      if (!exportedMembers.length) return

      const className = exportedMembers[0]
      this.addPlugin({
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, './service-template.js'),
        fileName: path.basename(file),
        options: {
          className,
          propName: className.slice(0,1).toLowerCase() + className.substring(1),
          moduleName: file,
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

```
// ~/modules/service-template.js
import { <%= options.className %> } from '<%= options.moduleName %>'

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  const <%= options.propName %> = new <%= options.className %> (app)
  inject('<%= options.propName %>', <%= options.propName %>)
}
```

Install this module under the [`modules`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-modules/) array in your Nuxt config:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  modules: [
    '~/modules/service-loader'
  ],
}
```